# Getting WebBrowser vertical offset in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a windows phone 8 app.  The first page contains a WebBrowser control with some custom HTML in it.  When the user clicks one of the links in the HTML it navigates to a second page.  As the HTML is taller than the screen i would like to store the vertical offset of the HTMl so when they come back to the first page they are were they were.

The problem is ... I cannot seem to use the HTML.InvokeScript() command when either the HTML or the application are "Navigating" to another page.  It throws an exception.  That means I need to put the calls to get and set the offset in code that isn't directly called by one of the navigating methods.

Comment: Which exception does it throws?

Comment: Without adding more code to your question, it's difficult to say where the error might be.